# How to create URLs like an articles name in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get articles from the database with a function that load articles in `single_view.php` the url is being like `www.example/Blog/function`.

I want to create my url with my articles name like
`www.example.com/Blog/my-article-name.html`

How can I do it in CodeIgniter?

Comment: have you set up a route to handle that? along the lines of `$route['blog(/:any)*'] = "blog/article";`

Comment: You could start by reading the CodeIgniter documentation and looking at the easy tutorial that's included in the docs.  Seriously, this is one of the laziest questions I've seen in a long time.

Comment: in /application/config/routes.php - you should read up on routes though. My example implies there's a blog controller and an article method. Also, you should use one of the uri segments for the article ID cause getting it to work on slug alone could be disasterous.

Comment: @KaiQing how could it be disastrous? I've been using slug along with no ill-effect. You just have to make sure the slug is unique. It will be as good as any id... Also you don't need routes to accomplish this.

Comment: @Alex - leave anything to human error and find out the hard way. I work in a client industry. Leave it to clients to do something stupid like name 300 events all the same exact thing with different dates so they appear on a calendar. Go right ahead and use slug if you are careful yourself, but take a good gander at the OP in this question. Do you have the confidence they have the foresight? Because I sure don't.

Comment: I see your point, but its just a matter of coding in validation/uniqueness which if you aren't willing to do then disastrous it would be. I make sure no slug is the same, incrementing them as you would an image name if the name already exists. Using this lib:  https://github.com/ericbarnes/CodeIgniter-Slug-Library

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['blog(/:any)*'] = "blog/article"
```

in application/conig/routes

OR

If you know which article you'll go on clicking then for every click you can create a function in the controller but I believe it will take a lot of effort and code size will increase, if you have many article, so go for the route solution.